# Wait for async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm aware this is a common problem asked by developers but I can't seem to find anyone who has the same issue as me.

I've got a game i'm creating, this game has lots of factories that when called return a game object, such as a player. Before the game even starts, i need to make sure all the images required are loaded, i did this by simply converting the .onload event into a promise, and placing that into an async function with an await call. However, due to changes in how i'm organizing the game, i will need to handle image loading in those factories that create game objects. This is a problem because now the game doesn't know when all the images are loaded. I thought I might be able to make those factories asynchronous and `await` on them, they will have an async function call that is also awaited on, but I don't believe this is possible. So abstracted, this is what I want:

I have a promise *`gotBanana`*, which resolves once I have gotten my banana.

this is in an async function called, *`getBananas()`*, which gets lots of bananas in the loop, it waits for the *`gotBanana`* promise to resolve every loop iteration.

I want to put this in another (probably async) function, but I want that function to await for the *`getBananas()`* function to finish.

Is it possible to do this or do i need to handle this situation in a different manner?

Comment: Can you write some code?? for what you require?? that might be better

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're looking for [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) that resolves all promises in parallel and return promise when it will be done. So you just need to map all your assets (images or other) and await it.

Comment: Ahh that could work, it'll require me to move around how things work but i was actually looking for something like that when i first started on the system.